# style.styleSheet.cssText not working on IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

What's the best way similar to below function,

that works in all browsers and any version of it specially in IE.

```
var head  = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var style = document.createElement('style');
css = "some style here"
style.type = 'text/css';

if (style.styleSheet){
  #Problem here: This is works for IE8 and below BUT not in higher version.
  style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}

head.appendChild(style);
```

Comment: I try to test your code with IE 11, document mode IE 9, IE 8, IE 10 and 11. I find that your code is only working with IE 11. I check the documentation and find that compatibility of cssText property is unknown for IE. Also the older versions of IE are not supported. So it is recommended to use the latest version of IE which is IE 11 may help you to avoid this issue. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/cssText

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try loading the css directly into the header if there is no css.styleSheet object.

Had no time testing thins but i think it should work. If you have any questions ask. :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function appendStyle(styles) {
  var css = document.createElement('style');
  css.type = 'text/css';

  if (css.styleSheet) css.styleSheet.cssText = styles;
  else css.appendChild(document.createTextNode(styles));

  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css);
}

var styles = '#header { color: white }';

window.onload = function() { appendStyle(styles) };
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Iwolf thank you for the answer, i'll do some testing w/ diff browsers and let you know :)

Comment: This is the same method that `style-loader` does it. :]
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader/blob/master/src/addStyles.js#L375-L390